# I have an input inside a while-loop that print 2 times the input beside one time , here is the code bellow and the console

Tags: python, while-loop, boolean

i have problem in this section of code

```
while again:
            if input("Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass:") == "n":
                print(l_dealer_cards)
                again = False
            elif input("Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass:") == "y":
                player_cards()
                if score(l_player_cards) > 21:
                    print(
                        f" Your cards: {l_player_cards}, current score: {score(l_player_cards)} \n "
                        f"over 21 you lose ")
                    again = False
                    play = False
                    D_again = False
                else:
                    print(
                        f" Your cards: {l_player_cards}, "
                        f"current score: {score(l_player_cards)} \n  Computer's first card: {l_dealer_cards[0]}")
            else:
                again = False
```

here is the console :

```
 Your cards: [4, 9], current score: 13 
  Computer's first card: 10
Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass:y
Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass:y
 Your cards: [4, 9, 10], current score: 23 
 over 21 you lose
```

and here is the the complete code :

```
import random
from udemy.Day11 import art

############### Our Blackjack House Rules #####################

# The deck is unlimited in size.
# There are no jokers.
# The Jack/Queen/King all count as 10.
# The Ace can count as 11 or 1.
# Use the following list as the deck of cards:
# cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
# The cards in the list have equal probability of being drawn.
# Cards are not removed from the deck as they are drawn.
# The computer is the dealer.

cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
l_player_cards = []
l_dealer_cards = []
dealer = 0
player = 0


def dealer_cards():
    l_dealer_cards.append(random.choice(cards))
    return l_dealer_cards


def player_cards():
    l_player_cards.append(random.choice(cards))
    return l_player_cards


def score(p_list):
    result = 0
    for card in p_list:
        result += card
    return result


def starting_cards():
    for i in range(2):
        a = player_cards()
        b = dealer_cards()
    print(
        f" Your cards: {l_player_cards}, current score: {score(l_player_cards)} \n  Computer's first card: {l_dealer_cards[0]}")


def black_jack(a):
    if score(a) == 21:
        return True
    else:
        return False


play = True
again = True
D_again = True

while play:
    if input("Do you want to play a game of Blackjack? Type 'y' or 'n':") == "n":
        play = False
    print(art.logo)
    starting_cards()
    if black_jack(l_player_cards) and not black_jack(l_dealer_cards):
        print(f" BLACK JACK {score(l_player_cards)} you win !! ")
        play = False
    elif black_jack(l_dealer_cards):
        print(f"{l_dealer_cards} BLACK JACK {score(l_dealer_cards)} dealer Win !!")
        play = False

    else:

        while again:
            if input("Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass:") == "n":
                print(l_dealer_cards)
                again = False
            elif input("Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass:") == "y":
                player_cards()
                if score(l_player_cards) > 21:
                    print(
                        f" Your cards: {l_player_cards}, current score: {score(l_player_cards)} \n "
                        f"over 21 you lose ")
                    again = False
                    play = False
                    D_again = False
                else:
                    print(
                        f" Your cards: {l_player_cards}, "
                        f"current score: {score(l_player_cards)} \n  Computer's first card: {l_dealer_cards[0]}")
            else:
                again = False
        player = score(l_player_cards)

        while D_again:
            if score(l_dealer_cards) > 21:
                print(" Dealer over 21 you win ")
                D_again = False
            elif score(l_dealer_cards) < 17:
                dealer_cards()
                print(
                    f"dealer get Card \n"
                    f" Your cards: {l_player_cards}, current score: {score(l_player_cards)} \n "
                    f" Dealer's cards: {l_dealer_cards}, current score: {score(l_dealer_cards)}")
            else:
                D_again = False
        dealer = score(l_dealer_cards)
        play = False

if player < dealer <= 21:
    print("you lose")
elif dealer < player <= 21:
    print("you win !!")
elif dealer == player != 21 and dealer > 17:
    print("it's a draw !! ")
```

```
 Your cards: [4, 9], current score: 13 
  Computer's first card: 10
Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass:y
Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass:y
 Your cards: [4, 9, 10], current score: 23 
 over 21 you lose
```

i need to get only one question only one printed input "Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass:"

Comment: Store the input response instead of asking for it twice

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the input twice, rather store it.
Here's my code:

```
while again:
    input = input("Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass:")
    if input == "n":
        print(l_dealer_cards)
        again = False
    elif input == "y":
        player_cards()
        if score(l_player_cards) > 21:
            print(
                f" Your cards: {l_player_cards}, current score: {score(l_player_cards)} \n "
                f"over 21 you lose ")
            again = False
            play = False
            D_again = False
        else:
            print(
                f" Your cards: {l_player_cards}, "
                f"current score: {score(l_player_cards)} \n  Computer's first card: {l_dealer_cards[0]}")
    else:
        again = False
```